# Evaluating an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Here is the input:

```
Integrate[E^(2 I*t)/(2*Pi*(E^(I*t) - z)), {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

and here the output:

> ConditionalExpression[0, Re[z] <= 0 && (ArcSin[Im[z]] ∉ Reals || Re[ArcSin[Im[z]]] >= π || Sqrt[1 - Im[z]^2] + Re[z] <= 0 || π + Re[ArcSin[Im[z]]] <= 0)]

this is the Cauchy integral represantation of the function `z` assuming the curve is the unitary circle, so the result must be `z`. Now if I put a specific value of `z` I obtain the correct result for `z` (the value which I put). How can I solve the problem?

Consider that `abs[z]<1` and if I put this assumptions I obtain that:

```
Integrate[E^(2 I*t)/(2*Pi*(E^(I*t) - z)), {t, 0, 2 Pi},  Assumptions -> Abs[z] < 1]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[0, Re[z] <= 0]
> ```

Comment: It seems there is a bug here.  Even a classical Cauchy integral `Integrate[1/(E^(I*t) - z), {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> {Abs[z] < 1}] `does not evaluate correctly yielding `ConditionalExpression[-((2 \[Pi])/z), Re[z] <= 0] `.

Comment: The usual trick seems to work though : `FullSimplify[
 Integrate[
  w/(2 Pi I (w - z)), {w, 1, 1 + I, -1 + I, -1 - I, 1 - I, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {Abs[z] < 1}], Assumptions -> {Abs[z] < 1}]` and `FullSimplify[
 Integrate[
  1/(2 Pi I (w - z)), {w, 1 + I, -1 + I, -1 - I, 1 - I, 1 + I}, 
  Assumptions -> {Abs[z] < 1}], Assumptions -> {Abs[z] < 1}]`.

Answer (score 2):

As shown by [b.gatessucks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73964/evaluating-an-integral#comment202881_73964):

We can get an answer through [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) function.

```
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[
  w/(2 Pi I (w - z)), {w, 1, 1 + I, -1 + I, -1 - I, 1 - I, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {Abs[z] < 1}], Assumptions -> {Abs[z] < 1}]
```

> 0

```
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[
  1/(2 Pi I (w - z)), {w, 1 + I, -1 + I, -1 - I, 1 - I, 1 + I}, 
  Assumptions -> {Abs[z] < 1}], Assumptions -> {Abs[z] < 1}]
```

> 1